# Communication between 32 bit and 64 bit systems

Tags: c++

I have two different systems, one running on 32 bit machine and other on 64 bit machine. The software on these systems are written in C++ and are compiled using respective GNU compilers on linux. I have defined an interface protocol for communication but am facing some problems in exchanging data. The systems are connected over ethernet. Are there some changes required to be undertaken to the data types like long in order to ensure that they  systems communicate without any problem?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on how your protocol is designed and implemented. How exactly is the data formatted? Without more details your question cannot be answered.

Comment: If you protocol is correctly representing the data this should be possible. It's therefore likely your protocol.

Comment: `#include <cstdint>` and build your protocol are the types within that file that have a defined size regardless of the underlying platform.  I suppose padding could also be different between the two, that's also something to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Usually when communicating over the network the protocol defines not only the size of the data but also the endianness (see htons and ntohs methods for example).
An easy way to go could be to serialize data with something like Google protocol buffers which will make it platform size independant.

Comment: I am using htons and ntohs prior to sending on the network. I will check google protocol buffers and see if it can help me